# Got memory leak while parsing large xml files from url using TBXML with ARC on

Tags: objective-c, xml, automatic-ref-counting, tbxml

I am using TBXML to parse XML files from an url and I have ARC on. But I got memory leak for the following code:

```
- (void)readXmlFromUrl:(NSString*)url
{
    NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:aUrl];
    TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLData:data];
//    data = nil;
//    NSLog(@"Reading from %@", url);
    // If TBXML found a root node, process element and iterate all children
    if (tbxml.rootXMLElement) {
        NSLog(@"Root Found");
        [self traverseElement:tbxml.rootXMLElement];
    }

//    data = nil;
//    aUrl = nil;
//    tbxml = nil;
//    NSLog(@"Retain count for TBXML %d", tbxml.retainCount);
}
```

I attached an image of memory leak. 
Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're building with ARC when running the static analyzer? ARC might only be turned on for some configurations, but Analyze uses a different one.

Comment: I turned ARC on when I created the project

Answer (score 1):

Not a leak but likely a bug in the static analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

my answer was bogus didnt see you were using ARC

Comment: He's using ARC, so no explicit autorelease is needed.

Comment: ah yes, why would arc ever show a warning like that - ARC == not my job to release. point taken. So glad I dont use ARC.